# In this tensorflow neural style transfer tutorial, why is this high pass filter coded this way?

Tags: tensorflow, graphics

In this tutorial, https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/style_transfer :

There's a function:

```
    def high_pass_x_y(image):
  x_var = image[:,:,1:,:] - image[:,:,:-1,:]
  y_var = image[:,1:,:,:] - image[:,:-1,:,:]

  return x_var, y_var
```

Which produces a difference image, and eventually used in

```
x_deltas, y_deltas = high_pass_x_y(content_image)

plt.figure(figsize=(14,10))
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
imshow(clip_0_1(2*y_deltas+0.5), "Horizontal Deltas: Original")

plt.subplot(2,2,2)
imshow(clip_0_1(2*x_deltas+0.5), "Vertical Deltas: Original")
```

What is the point of 2*Delta+0.5? Is this empirically chosen to accentuate the contrast between adjacent pixels?